# as.Date not returning the date part from a POSIXt object

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I am trying to get the date part of a date-time POSIXt object in R I get a number instead.

Here is my data:

```
    y <- "2017-01-03 19:59:00"
```

Using following code:

```
    as.Date(as.POSIXct(y))
```

I get this number: `17169`. I am in Eastern Time Zone (UTC-05:00) and have checked to make sure `y` is a `POSIXt` class. I am out of options and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want as a result? If it's just `2017-01-03` you can do `sub(' .*', '', y)`

Comment: @C.Braun I want the date part in a date format. The way you mentioned will create a character.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine in my system,  have a look here
:

[image]

Comment: That is weird. It worked fine on my machine previously as well. I though maybe some packages have been updated that I am not aware of and it does not work properly anymore.

Comment: well. I figured it out. I was using the conversion in an ifelse function and that was the bug with ifelse. as I switched to if-else the problem is resolved. Thanks everyone